# How to position two elements at the center of a `<div>` element

Tags: html, css, layout

I have two `<p>` elements inside a `<div>` element, and want to position them at the center of the `<div>` element. e.g.

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <p class="above">some text</p>
   <p class="below">other text</p>
</div>
```

Note: the `<div>` element itself is not positioned at the center of the browser window, so the positioning of `<p>` elements is only relative.

Comment: Does `#mydiv` have a fixed height? Are you looking to horizontally or vertically center your content?

Comment: @Wex, no, `#mydiv` does not have a fixed height, and will scale as screen/window size changes. I want to position them at the center both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**

Add following css rules in `#mydiv`

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

**Like This**

```
#mydiv{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;

    display:table-cell; /* Added rule - Note: IE8+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    vertical-align:middle; /* Added rule */
}

#mydiv p{
    text-align:center;
}​
```

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kcYsk/1/)

Comment: this only centers the elements horizontally but not vertically. I want them to be at the center of the `<div>` in both dimensions. Thanks.

Comment: @MLister: Updated my answer with your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```css
text-align: center;
```

for text.

```css
margin: 0 auto;
```

for block level elements like a div.

Comment: this only centers the elements horizontally but not vertically. I want them to be at the center of the `<div>` in both dimensions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try;

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

to your `p`

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/F7KFz/)*** is a Live Demo

If you want to center both vertically and horizontally, you may try **[Dead Center](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html)**

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/QPdHG/2/)*** is a demo showing centering a div **Both Vertically and Horizontally**

Comment: this only centers the elements horizontally but not vertically. I want them to be at the center of the `<div>` in both dimensions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align: center;
```

It's worked for me.

Comment: this only centers the elements horizontally but not vertically. I want them to be at the center of the `<div>` in both dimensions. Thanks.